# Why can't all change sets be found when accepting change sets?

Tags: rtc

Occasionally when I am accepting I change set I receive the following message :

[image]

To resolve this I apply the changes as a patch and then 'Merge into workspace' the changes
Why cannot all of the change sets be found ? Is there a danger my code could become out of sync with the flow target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The danger is not so much the out of sync, but the *integrity* of the resulting code, once the patches are applied:
You are accepting change set based on *other* change sets that are not delivered.
There is no guarantee that it works.

As explained in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/28853/issue-accepting-change-sets-from-flow-target):

> In S1, suppose there are two change sets that have modified file `foo.java`: `CS-23` and `CS-35`.
>   You have requested `CS-35`, but not `CS-23`.
>   But the state of file `foo.java` in `CS-35` contains the changes from `CS-23`... So you can't get `CS-35` unless you also have `CS-23` (i.e. "the change set that led up to this change set").

It is ok for a developer A to *not* deliver all his/her change set, provided he/she delivers *all* change sets up to a certain point.

The warning appears in case of a partial deliver (the developer delivers `B`, based on change set `A`, but does *not* deliver change set `A`)

That might not be an issue, if there is no functional dependency (similar to [`git cherry-pick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)) between the two change sets (if `B` doesn't rely on code in `A` to compile, for instance).

Comment: I think I understand, merging the 'pending patch' will merge just the latest change set. This is ok because I just need the most up to date change set for this stream. The disadvantage is though I cannot view the past change sets which made this change set, unless of course I view in the original stream (where the change set was created) ?

Comment: @user470184 not only can you *not* see past change set, but if your change set only works because of a feature introduced in said invisible past change set, what you just accepted and applied in your local workspace won't work.

Comment: @user470184 it is a problem similar to `git cherry-pick`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309

Comment: but if said feature (by feature I'm assuming you mean new code) is available in most recent version of change set then it should work ?

Comment: @user470184 yes. By feature, I meant indeed new code like, for instance, a function. If you accept '`a.foo()`', but function `foo()` is defined in an *un-delivered* change set... your latest accept wouldn't compile properly.

Comment: ok but as long as I have all latest change sets within said stream then code will be up to date ?

Comment: @user470184 if you have *all* the latest within said stream, yes, your code will be up-to-date. The fact that you have this warning though ("Confirm Content Accept") means you don't have all latest change sets.

Comment: sorry if I'm dragging this out, im not sure I fully understand. Will I not have latest change set for each component since when I accept a change set, the accepted change set is the latest one. I may not have the change sets leading up to the latest change set, this is acceptable if the code compiles based on the change sets delivered for current stream.

Comment: @user470184 the fact that the accepted change set is "the latest one" doesn't mean it includes *all* the changes from the source stream. The warning you got means that it relies on other change set (that you don't have), but, as you said, it still can work. By "latest", I mean the most recent change set produced on the *source* stream.

Comment: is this not a major issue for source control then if when merging two streams I cannot guarantee that all change sets in stream i'm merging from are also in stream I'm merging to ?

Comment: @user470184 yes, which is why you see this warning: merging two streams in RTC means accepting change set from one stream and delivering them to the other (as I explained to you earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13647350/6309): if a developer didn't have delivered *all* his/her change sets, the warning you see if a consequence. You can choose to stop the merge right there and ask for the missing change set, or you can decide it is good enough, and go on with the merge.

Comment: the missing change set, is this a change set that is 'checked in' but not delivered ?

Comment: By deciding it is 'good enough' , will this not cause source code differences between two streams, because this is just accepting some of the change sets in stream I'm merging from, when I should be accepting all of the change sets.

Comment: @user470184 yes, checked in, not delivered. As long as what you are accepting compile and includes the expected features, it is ok. The developer might not have delivered a previous change set with a feature too comple to be delivered just now. It is mainly a communication and project management issue.