# How to find hidden change sets

Tags: rtc

This question is linked to :

[Why can't all change sets be found when accepting change sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197628/why-cant-all-change-sets-be-found-when-accepting-change-sets)

If RTC discovers that by accepting a change set some of the change sets which depend on this change set will not be accepted, is it possible to view what these change sets are ?

[image]

It seems very risky to accept a change set and not be 100% sure that the change sets being accepted contain same source code file changes as was intended by developer who delivered the change sets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is adding the repo workspace of the developer having delivered on the *source* stream.

You would add that repo workspace as a flow target of your own repo workspace (the one you are using for the merge)

By setting that new flow target as current, you can quickly see what change set you are missing.

---

Of course, the real issue is that what I just proposed doesn't scale: if you have multiple developers having made *partial* delivers (with missing intermediate change sets), then you would need to have a look in turn to each developer's repo workspaces.

That is why you have since 2007(!) the "blocker" Work Item "[Enhancement 24822](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=24822)":

> "Confirm Content Accept" dialog should be more specific (offer to fill in gaps when a gap exception occurs)

... but it is *still* unresolved, even in the latest RTC4.x.

Comment: it seems to me thats its up to the developer to ensure that all un-checked in changes are delivered to the stream. If there are change sets which just exist within the developers workspace then I don't think the build engineer should be ensuring that they are delivered to the stream. I